# Does the Windows 7 CLI command "shutdown" ensure all disk writes occur before power ends?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, backup, cache

I have a Windows 7 Batch file, (that I wrote), that opens a database program, and when the program is exitted, copies a large number of files from one folder to another folder on the same hard disk, following the termination of the program that was using them. Backing up the program database in other words. Originally the database was small and I didn't mind sitting there watching the backup complete before shutting down the PC. The database has grown significatly, (for me), over time and now it takes a while to complete. I've recently added a "shutdown" command to the script which appears to work as expected, however I'm now concerned that the database is being fully written prior to the PC powering down.
This is my Batch file:

```
REM This script starts Brother Keeper and then copies all the files to the Backup
REM folder D:\Libraries\Downloads\Brothers Keeper\Data Backups when it closes.

echo normal mode
start "Brothers Keeper 7" /wait "D:\Program Files (x86)\Brother's Keeper 7\Bk7w.exe"
echo
echo
echo
@echo off
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Do you want to Back-Up the Brothers Keeper Database? (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
SET /P SHUTDOWN=Do you want to Shutdown the PC when completed? (Y/[N])?
@echo on

XXCOPY "D:\Program Files (x86)\Brother's Keeper 7" "D:\Libraries\Downloads\Brothers Keeper\Data Backups" /V2 /C /I /H /R /Y /E /oN"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\XXCOPY_Error_Log.log" /Fo"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\Backup_Routine_Output.log"
type "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\XXCOPY_Error_Log.log">>"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\Backup_Routine_Output.log"
XXCOPY "D:\Libraries\Documents\Geneology" "D:\Libraries\Downloads\Brothers Keeper\Data Backups" /V2 /C /I /H /R /Y /E /oN"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\XXCOPY_Error_Log.log" /Fo"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\Backup_Routine_Output_2.log"
type "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\Backup_Routine_Output_2.log">>"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\Backup_Routine_Output.log"
type "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\XXCOPY_Error_Log.log">>"C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\Backup_Routine_Output.log"
del "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\Backup_Routine_Output_2.log"
del "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Brothers Keeper Backup Data\XXCOPY_Error_Log.log"
echo
IF /I "%SHUTDOWN%" EQU "Y" ( shutdown.exe /s /t 00 )
echo "Backup Completed. Press a key to end."
pause
```

I used xxcopy because it's supposed to confirm the actual writing of the file to disk, but of course there's all that damned caching going on.
My questions are:
Windows and hard disks are notorious for caching to improve performance. Can I be sure that all of the disk writes are done before the PC powers down?
Is there a command similar to the Unix sync sync sync to force Windows 7/the disks to complete the writes cached available from the batch CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any shutdown triggered by software is considered safe.

Software shutdowns will call the Windows shutdown process which will close applications, save data as necessary, commit relevant changes in the registry and then flush disk caches before finally calling the firmware functions that tell the system to turn off power.

The only shutdowns that are not guaranteed to write changes to disk are you holding the power button and forcing an immediate shutdown and physically removing power by unplugging the cord or pulling the battery.

If you are still paranoid though there is a Microsoft Sysinternals tool called [sync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync) that can flush disk caches, but you will need to run it as administrator which might pose some issues in a user executed script.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, just what I wanted to know. And yes I am still paranoid, (that's why I started using xxcopy), and will investigate using Sync too. Aside from copying the database to the same disk, I also regularly clone the disk, and copy both Master and Backup copies of the database to a NAS. I'm paranoid because the database represents about 20 years of strenuous personal effort tracing my family history. Losing it would be unthinkable.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent command to the Linux `sync` was written by Mark Russinovich -
[sync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/sync):

> UNIX provides a standard utility called Sync, which can be used to
> direct the operating system to flush all file system data to disk in
> order to insure that it is stable and won't be lost in case of a
> system failure. Otherwise, any modified data present in the cache
> would be lost. Here is an equivalent that I wrote, called Sync, that
> works on all versions of Windows. Use it whenever you want to know
> that modified file data is safely stored on your hard drives.
> **Unfortunately, Sync requires administrative privileges to run**. This version also lets you flush removable drives such as ZIP drives.

Note that the documentation for the
[shutdown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)
says this:

> `/f` : Forces running applications to close without warning users.
> Caution: Using the /f option might result in loss of unsaved data. /m
> \  Specifies the target computer. Can't be used with the
> /l option.
>
> `/t <xxx>` : Sets the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
> The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30. If
> the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is implied.

Which implies that for `/t 0` executing apps will not be closed forcefully.